# El header de mi página no encuadra con el viewport

Tags: css, html5

Estoy creando una página de herramientas. Ya tengo prácticamente la página completa, así que comencé a hacerla **responsiva**.

Para ir probando cómo se vería en las diferentes resoluciones, **ajusté** la anchura del **viewport** a la altura mínima requerida para que se cumplan las condiciones. Voy en la parte de **tablets**.
Todo marchaba bien, hasta que…

[image: Excedente.]

… me da tremendo **excedente**. He probado quitarlo poniendo el `width: auto` y el `margin-left: auto` a la parte derecha de mi cabecera (la dividí por partes), pero no funcionó.

**No quiero retirar el excedente**, sino que me quede un poco más a la izquierda para que se **ajuste** de manera correcta al **viewport**.

Aquí está el código:

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>TMnWTools - Principal</title>
        <script src="../code/tmnwtools.js"></script>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="../code/style.css">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=1024px;, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta charset="UTF-8">
    </head>
    
    
    
    <body>
    
    <header> <div id="navbar_left"><a href="es.howtouse.html"><img src="../code/assets/icons/help.png" class="icon" alt="Settings"></a></div>
    <a href="tmnwtools.html"><img src="../code/assets/logo.png" alt="TextTool" id="logo"></a><div id="navbar_right"><p id="langchange">Offered by TechMan Walker in:</p><select id="language"><option value="en">English&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;▼</option><option value="es">Español&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp▼</option></select></div></div>
    <div style="margin-bottom: 30px;"></header>
    
    <section>
    <ul id="tool_list">
        <li><p id="evadecommrulesmod">Evade community rules:</p><textarea id="evadetext" rows="4" placeholder="Type here your text."></textarea>
        <div class="button" id="processEvasingText">Process</div>
        <br>
        <p id="resultEvadeArea">Results will appear here. Note: if the letters are wrong, try to process again.</p>
        </li>
        
        <li><p id="reversetextmod">Reverse text:</p><textarea id="reversetext" rows="4" placeholder="Type here your text."></textarea>
        <div class="button" id="processReversingText">Process</div>
        <br>
        <p id="resultReverseArea">Results will appear here.</p>
        </li>
        
        <li><p id="genkeymod">Generate password:</p>
            <input type="number" placeholder="Length (8)" id="passwordlength">
            <div class="onoffbutton" id="passwordNumbers">Numbers</div>
            <div class="onoffbutton"  id="passwordSymbols">Symbols</div>
            <div class="button" id="generatePassword">Generate</div>
        <br>
        <p id="resultPasswordArea">Results will appear here.</p>
        </li>
        
        <a href="../code/tmnwtools.min.js"><li><image class="icon" src="../code/assets/icons/down-arrow.png" ><p id="downlibmod">Download the library</p></li></a>
    </ul>
    </section>
    
    <script src="../code/tmnwtools.js"></script>
    <script src="../code/mainpage.js"></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/**TODO ESTÁ ORDENADO DE LA A A LA Z**/

/* ***** CLASES ***** */

/* Botones */
.button {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background-color: #151517;
    padding: 5px 1em;;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 8px;
    width: auto;
}

.centerinput {
    padding: 8px;
    background-color: #151517;
    color: #cccccd;
    display: inline;
    justify-content: center;
}

/* Íconos*/
.icon {
    width: 30px;
    padding: 8px;
}

/* Botones que se encienden y apagan */
.onoffbutton {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 5px 1em;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 8px;
    width: auto;
    background-color: #550000;
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 15px #450000;
    transition: background-color 0.25s,
    box-shadow 0.25s;
}


/* ** ELEMENTOS CON IDENTIFICACIÓN ** */

/* Texto para cambiar idioma */
#langchange {font-size: 0.5em; margin-right: 1em;}

/* Barra superior */ 
header {
    background-color: #333339;
    padding: 5px;
    width: 100%;
    height: 50px;
    display: flex;
    align-content: center;
    align-items: center;
}

/* Logotipo */
header #logo {
    background-color: #00000000;
    width: 90px;
    display: flex;
    align-self: center;
}

/* Barra superior - División izquierda */ 
#navbar_left {
    width: 10%;
    padding-right: auto;
    margin-left: 4px;
}

/* Barra superior - División derecha */
#navbar_right {
    margin: auto;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
}

#tool_list > a > li {
    background-color: #242430;
    padding: 1em 1.2em;
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 8px;
    margin-top: 1em;
    margin-right: 1em;
}

#tool_list > li {
    background-color: #242430;
    padding: 1em 1.2em;
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 8px;
    margin-top: 1em;
    margin-right: 1em;
} 

/* ***** ETIQUETAS ***** */

/* Enlaces */
a {
    text-decoration: none;
    font-style: none;
    color: #cccccd;
}

/* Ítems de lista con enlace */
a li {
    background-color: #242430;
    ;
    padding: 15px 15px;
    padding-left: 18px;
    border: 1px solid #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 8px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-style: none;
    color: #cccccd;
}

/* Fondo de tema oscuro */
body {
    background-color: #070707;
    margin: 0px;
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #cccccd;
    font-family: Acherus;
    word-break: break-word;
}

/* Raíz */
html {
    font-size: 16px;
}

/* Campos de texto */
input {
    margin: 3px 0px;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    padding: 5px;
    background-color: #151517;
    color: #cccccd;
    width: 100%;
}

/* Selector de idioma */
select {
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    border-radius: 2px;
    color: #000000;
    linear-gradient:none;
    overflow: hidden;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -moz-appearance: none;
    appearance: none;
    padding: 0.7em;
}

/* Áreas de texto */
textarea {
    margin: 3px 0px;
    margin-bottom: 1em;
    padding: 0.5em 0.5em;
    background-color: #151517;
    color: #cccccd;
    width: 100%;
}

/* Listas */
ul {
    list-style: none;
    text-decoration: none;
}

/* ***** EXTRAS ***** */

@font-face {
    font-family: Acherus;
    src: url("assets/fonts/acherus.ttf");
}

/* *************MEDIA QUERIES************* */

/* Pantallas de tablet */

@media screen and (min-width: 1024px) {

    header {
        position: relative;
        width: 100%;
        justify-content: center;
        padding: 1rem;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }
    
    html {
        font-size: 18px;
    }
    
    input {
        font-size: 1rem;
    } 
    
    p {
        font-size: 1rem;
    }
    
    select {
        font-size:  0.8rem;
    }
    
    textarea {
        font-size: 1rem;
    }
    
    ul {
        margin: 1rem 0.8rem 3rem 3rem;
    }
    
    #langchange {
        font-size: 0.8rem;
    }
    
    #logo {
        margin: 0 auto;
    }
    
    #navbar_left {
        position: absolute;
        width: auto;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        left: 0;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }
    
    #navbar_right {
        position: absolute;
        width: auto;
        margin-left: auto;
        top: 0;
        bottom: 0;
        right: 0;
        display: flex;
        align-items: center;
    }
}
```

Gracias y espero me puedas ayudar. **¡Ten un lindo día! ❂**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Primero que funcionalidad tiene este div que estas colocando ? `<div style="margin-bottom: 30px;"></div>` esto puede ser interpretado como una línea de 30px.

Segundo justamente después de la etiqueta select tienes otro problema, las aperturas y cierres no concuerdan [image: error de etiquetas]

Tercero y ultimo a el `header` yo le colocaría justify-content space-between y a el navbar-right le quitaría el margen automático y le pondría justify-content flex-end.

Comment: ¡Muchas gracias! Me diste la base para darle fin a todos los errores. Le puse justify-content: space-between y funciona bien. No sé cómo pero logré quitar el excedente que se me hizo, y me di cuenta que no cerré ese div  y sí, es una línea :p. ¡Ten un lindo día!